# sys.servers - what table was in SQL 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2005 in the sys.servers information about mapped remote SQL Server instance is stored.

How were remote servers mapped in SQL Server 2000?

BR, Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the compatibility table in 2005 `sys.sysservers`, mentioned in [this MSDN library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188740.aspx), I would say that the catalogue view/ system table is called `sysservers` in 2000.